# Multiple squares being grouped as one with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

Attempting to define a square within a provided image but some are getting grouped together
I'm assuming its some kind of threshold issue but I haven't found anything to solve this so far

[image: finding 8 points instead of 2 different squares]

code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import time
def empty(a):
    pass
 
cv.namedWindow("Params")
cv.resizeWindow("Params",640,240)
cv.createTrackbar("THRESH1","Params",150,255,empty)
cv.createTrackbar("THRESH2","Params",150,255,empty)
 
read = cv.imread("esult.jpg")
 
def getContours(img,imgContour):
 
 
 
    contours, herarchy = cv.findContours(img, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
   
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv.contourArea(cnt)
        if area>1000:
            peri = cv.arcLength(cnt, True)
            approx = cv.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.34 * peri, True)
            x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(approx)
            cv.rectangle(imgContour, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 5)
 
while(1):
    img = read
    imgContour = img.copy()
    gs = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
    threshold1 = cv.getTrackbarPos("THRESH1","Params")
    threshold2 = cv.getTrackbarPos("THRESH2","Params")
    Canny = cv.Canny(gs,threshold1,threshold2)
 
    getContours(Canny,imgContour)
 
    cv.imshow('gs', gs)
    cv.imshow('read',imgContour)
    cv.imshow('canny', Canny)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

these lines should be the main culprit:

```
       peri = cv.arcLength(cnt, True)
       approx = cv.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.34 * peri, True)
       x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(approx)
       cv.rectangle(imgContour, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 5)
```

I've tried changing the epson number but it doesn't do anything

Comment: That's because their border shares [connectivity](https://cvexplained.wordpress.com/tag/connected-component-labeling/). The border is identified as one contiguous contour. You can try to separate each square using, perhaps, some [morphology](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) (particularly, erosion) before computing their bounding boxes.

Comment: Another approach could involve working with the inner (child) contours of the squares instead of the external contour, since the inner border seems to be separated enough to break down the connectivity issue. Check [contour hierarchy](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) for more info.

Comment: input data required. can't debug what's already damaged from filtering. [mre]

Comment: 'findContours' is useless for this task. I would try to find lines by means of opencv and then detect if any combination of lines represents square.